# MacOS 12.6 Numbers version 12.1 (7034.0.86) Day function in vlookup function

Tags: macos, numbers

I am attempting to use the calendar spreadsheet provide as a template with Numbers. In the month section there are dates in the even rows and large cells in the corresponding odd rows for whatever text you might want to enter.
In cell C10 is the number 25 which is the result of a formula C8+DURATION(1) where C8 has 18 derived from a similar formula referencing the week prior.

If I put the formula =C10 in cell D10, the result is as expected "25".

If I use that like this =VLOOKUP(C10,Table 1::F9:G13,2,)the result is from one row lower than it should be. In other words the returned valued is "Pack" not "Travel". The lookup range (in Table 1) looks like this:

`.  F.             G`

`9  25            Travel`

`10 26            Pack`

`11 27            Pack`

`12 28            Move`

I've tried using the T and String functions to convert the C10 but that doesn't work.
I've tried =VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("C10"),Table 1::F9:G13,2,) with the same result.
=VLOOKUP(25,Table 1::F9:G13,2,) returns the correct value, i.e. "Travel".

Can someone explain a way to sort out this formula or change it to work as I expect?

Comment: I know the calendar template in Numbers but it is still difficult to comprehend the structure and other details of your spreadsheet despite the descriptions you have provided. Perhaps one or more screenshots might help. Not 100% sure if this would help either but have you tried using exact match `0` as the type of match in the VLOOKUP()s in the spreadsheet?